# Generating C# classes based on XML request using ArrayOfString

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, serialization

I have the xml request and I need to generate c# classes for list structure .

Request :

```
  <soapenv:Envelope  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org"
      xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays ">
     <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:request>
         <tem:id>1</tem:id>
         <tem:list>
            <arr:string>Item1</arr:string>
            <arr:string>Item2</arr:string>
            <arr:string>Item3</arr:string>
         </tem:list>
      </tem:request>
   </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can somebody help me with this ? 
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a WSDL (service definition) file for the service you're trying to integrate with?

Comment: No , just the request .

Comment: The request is a string not classes.  Serialization produces a string.  You can get a string from my solution using doc.ToString().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have a WSDL file for the service, what you can do use the little known feature of Visual Studio which [Paste XML as Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/generating-data-type-classes-from-xml) that uses class generation features introduced in .NET 4.5.

The steps to use this feature are:

1. Create Class file that the XML to be inserted into.
2. With the cursor inside the class file, click Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML as Classes.

Visual Studio will then populate the class file with the generated classes for your XML request.

**Note:** Your example XML is currently malformed the `xmlns:tem` attribute is not closed on the envelope element. This feature will not work if the XML is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need classes.  I think in this case it is easier to parse a string and add just then items in the list.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> items = new List<string>(){ "Item1", "Item2", "Item3"};
            string xml = 
                "<soapenv:Envelope  xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org\"" +
                      " xmlns:arr=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">" +
                     "<soapenv:Header/>" +
                      "<soapenv:Body>" +
                      "<tem:request>" +
                         "<tem:id>1</tem:id>" +
                         "<tem:list>" +
                         "</tem:list>" +
                      "</tem:request>" +
                   "</soapenv:Body>" +
                  "</soapenv:Envelope>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace temNs = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("tem");
            XNamespace arrNs = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("arr");

            XElement list = doc.Descendants(temNs + "list").FirstOrDefault();

            List<XElement> xItems = items.Select(x => new XElement(arrNs + "string", x)).ToList();

            list.Add(xItems);
            doc.Save(FILENAME);
        }
    }
}
```